# Force reload of page with URL containing an anchor (#)

Tags: javascript

I want to reload a page like so :

```
window.location.href = url;
```

But given my url contains an anchor the previous instruction won't do anything.
How to deal with this issue ?
Thank you for the great help.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```js
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: it will reload a different URL in my case

Answer (score 1):

You can do `location.replace("https:/rickrolled.com");`
So, to redirect, you can do `location.replace(location.href);`

Or just do `location.reload();`

If it doesn't work, please send me a JSFiddle of your project.

Comment: Neither work. the latter is not possible in my case because it will reload the app at a different url.